# How to Add sorter in my custom product collection page

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, sorting, pagination, toolbar

[image]    my block is

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

public function getToolbarHtml()
{

    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');

}


<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?> //using this for pager
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>//ushing this for sorting
```

it's only display paging block i want to display both pager and sorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to call sortable parameter  at your theme.
Or can call like this way as well

```
<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did u set all the sort paramters on your toolbar? like

```
 // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
    public function getDefaultDirection(){
        return 'asc';
    }
    public function getAvailableOrders(){
        return array('date_creation'=> 'Date de Création','title'=>'titre','id'=>'ID');
    }
    public function getSortBy(){
        return 'id';
    }
```